# unique iOS notification each day of the year

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, notifications

I am really struggling to find an elegant, simple solution to this problem. Each day, at a user specified time(no need for them to specify the date, as the app will provide them notifications each and every day of the year), the user will receive a unique textual notification, with a unique audio notification (essentially will be an audio clip of me reading what is present in the day's textual notification) Please advise.

Comment: I've hesitated to try much after reading of a 64 notification limit and other ominous hurdles. I keep seeming to hit dead ends or too-complex-for-me solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You need design a backend service for delivering [push notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html). 
Just Host a cloud service on Amazon server use that to synchronize time with your application.

Once you are done with this send a request to your server for a request to fetch an Audio Clip or send text sms. Your text message is supposed to be send by your backend server using a [texting API](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms)

You CANNOT integrate this logic in your front-end because user can change its device time. 
And this will mess up your notifications.
You need to rely on your Could Hosting service for that. Try rapid protoyping using any of the following service:

1)[Amazon BanStalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).
2)[Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/?csw=1).

Also note that you need to have Paas cloud service which already have required framework to setup these things and easily provide you with API's to store audio and send text messages. Don't use Saas or Iaas service like Amazon Aws in which you have to setup everything manually

Comment: Might want to look at parse.com too.

Comment: I'd really like to avoid using the cloud

Comment: @ThomasBuckler It's not practical to do something like that. You can't upload so many audio files into your app bundle. App store will not approve it. Also , you dont have any API for sending text without users involvement. If everything could be done in frontend then we don't why do we have a backened at all.

Comment: How can you be sure the App Store won't approve it?

Comment: Because if you load so many file you bundle size will increase. There is a Hard limit of 2GB and 60 MB for executables. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/18_BestPractices/BestPractices.html

Comment: Moreover you app could not be downloaded over 3g. if it exceeds 10 MB

Comment: Also, everytimw you want to modify the audio clip or content of text message you need to send a upgrade to app store.

Comment: no modifications will be necessary. Except a yearly update.

Comment: Your call , easily development or easy maintenance.Select any one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38818/discussion-between-thomas-buckler-and-kunal-balani)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a backend that serves them to your application, or you can store the notifications using [NSKeyedArchiver](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) and look them up based on the day if they're never going to change (and if you update your app at least once a year).  The second option would be good if you want to just ship your app with 365 notifications, but if you can't do that then you have to serve them to the app.

Comment: Yes, my thought was to ship the app with all textual notifications and audio notifications included. not outside the app.

Comment: Then you'll just want to store them.  Your options for the notifications are core data and NSKeyedArchiver. Since it doesn't sound like you are going to have a large graph of objects that you need stored, I would recommend NSKeyedArchiver.  The actual audio files can just be included in your project and referenced by some URL scheme of your choice.

Comment: is it possible to use NSKeyedArchiver for the audio files as well? @JuJoDi

Comment: NSKeyedArchiver is for serializing and storing objects on disk, you can retrieve the audio files with something like AVPlayer to play to the user.